# Replacing $a$ to &a using shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I want to replace all the occurrences of `$[a-z|A-Z|0-9]$` to `&[a-z|A-Z|0-9]` using shell script. For example, `$HELLO$` should become `&HELLO`.

```
I/P - $HELLO$
o/P - &HELLO
```

I tried using sed to replace the string.

```
sed -i -e 's/$*$/&/g filename

I/P - $HELLO$
O/P - &HELLO&
```

But I am unable to make sure that the last $ is replaced by a blank space and not `&`

Comment: What did you try? Also your title is different from your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using grouping and backreference::

```
$ sed 's/\$\([a-zA-Z0-9]*\)\$/\&\1/g' <<< '$HELLO$'
&HELLO
```

Comment: I added character range to avoid greedy effect and `g` modifier.

Answer (score 1):

Solution using `awk`: This uses awk's inbuilt function `sub` to search and replace `$` sign and then `sub` is again used to replace `$` to `&`.

```
echo '$HELLO$' |awk '{sub(/\$/,"\\&");sub(/\$/,"")}1'
&HELLO
```